# Why is the keras model less accurate and not recognized?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I downloaded the mnist dataset (jpg) and created a model file with .hdf (.h5).
Images were recognized using the .h5 model, but the recognition rate is low..
.
The accuracy is low when actual compile..
Did I do something wrong?.
.
The image used the 28x28 image of the grayscale..

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import random

FILENAME = 'model.h5'

WIDTH = 28
HEIGHT = 28
EPOCHES = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 32

def create_dataset(img_folder):
    img_data_array=[]
    class_name=[]
   
    for path in os.listdir(img_folder):
        if path == ".DS_Store":
            continue
        for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(img_folder, path)):
            if file == ".DS_Store":
                continue
            image_path = os.path.join(img_folder, path,  file)

            image = cv2.imread( image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)


            image = cv2.resize(image, (HEIGHT, WIDTH),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            image = np.array(image)
            
            image = image.astype('float32')
            image /= 255 
            img_data_array.append(image)
            class_name.append(path)
    return img_data_array, class_name

img_data, class_name = create_dataset(r'/Users/animalman/Documents/test/grayscale/train')
test, test_class_name = create_dataset(r'/Users/animalman/Documents/test/grayscale/test')

target_dict = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(np.unique(class_name))}
target_val = [target_dict[class_name[i]] for i in range(len(class_name))]

test_dict = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(np.unique(test_class_name))}
test_val = [test_dict[test_class_name[i]] for i in range(len(test_class_name))]

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# tensor
history = model.fit(x=tf.cast(np.array(img_data), tf.float64), y=tf.cast(list(map(int,target_val)),tf.int32), epochs=EPOCHES, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, validation_split=0.33)

evaluate = model.evaluate(x=tf.cast(np.array(img_data), tf.float64), y=tf.cast(list(map(int,target_val)),tf.int32), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
print('Train:', evaluate)

test_evaluate = model.evaluate(x=tf.cast(np.array(test), tf.float64), y=tf.cast(list(map(int,test_val)),tf.int32), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
print('Test:', test_evaluate)

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('mnist', test_acc)


model.save(FILENAME)
```

...
...
Epoch 98/100
1257/1257 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 5.5190e-08 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 43.3440 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 99/100
1257/1257 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 4.0746e-08 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 43.3764 - val_accuracy: 0.1136
Epoch 100/100
1257/1257 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3033e-08 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 43.4628 - val_accuracy: 0.1136

..
..

Train: [14.343465805053711, 0.7074833512306213]
313/313 [==============================] - 0s 579us/step - loss: 14.7582 - accuracy: 0.6990
Test: [14.758186340332031, 0.6990000009536743]
313/313 [==============================] - 0s 850us/step - loss: 3887.2236 - accuracy: 0.6991
mnist : 0.6991000175476074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here

```
Epoch 100/100 1257/1257 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3033e-08 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 43.4628 - val_accuracy: 0.1136
```

You can see the training acc is `1.0` and validating acc is `0.1136`

-> Your model is **overfitting** to the training dataset.

About the overfitting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

Comment: Is it possible to overfit the data already used by extracting it from the mnist? Isn't it my code problem?

Comment: how does one solve the overfitting problem?  I noticed accuracy of 100% when I ran the sample https://github.com/dnishimoto/python-deep-learning/blob/master/CNN%20%20image%20classification.ipynb.